# Searching a Set in Swift

Tags: swift

I have something like the following

```
struct ht : Hashable {
                       var x : Int
                       var y : Int
                       var z : Int
                       //Edit added following func following Ahmad's comment
                       var hashValue: Int { return (x+y+z) }

                       static func == (lhs: ht, rhs: ht) -> Bool
                                          {
                                            return lhs.x == rhs.x 
                                                && lhs.y == rhs.y
                                                && lhs.z == rhs.z
                                          }
                     }

let defaultX  = 4

let searchForX = 7
//let searchForX = 1000000

var ss : Set<ht> = [ ht(x:1,y:2,z:3), ht(x:4,y:5,z:6), ht(x:7, y:8, z:100), ht(x:9, y:19, z:12)]
```

Does Swift have LINQ like functionality where I can search the set *ss* to retrieve the struct that matches searchForX = 7 as shown above to return (7, 8, 100)? If searchForX = 1000000 I want it to return (4, 5, 6), so failing over to returning the value where defaultX = 4

My current code uses loops. In C# you can use LINQ and specify .FirstOrDefault(...).

Is this possible in Swift?

Thank you

Comment: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/set/1848922-first is what you are looking for – but your code does not compile.

Comment: Please note that you cannot declare a set of non-hashable type; adding this code to a playground would generates an error: "error: MyPlayground.playground:165:10: error: type 's' does not conform to protocol 'Hashable'".

Comment: Hi Martin, I'm new to Swift, I wrote the code above in the Playground. .First(..) is sort of what I am looking for, but I want the .FirstOrDefault like functionality, so if the value is not found, it fails over to another element

Comment: Thanks Ahmad, as you can see, I am learning :-( I had not noticed this error in my playground as I was not showing that window

Comment: A added the func Ahmad, I "think" it is correct now

Answer (score 0):

Swift isn't really my thing but a ternary operator similar to the code below may move you along.

```
var answer = ss.first(where: { $0.x == searchForX }) ?? ss.first(where: { $0.x == defaultX })
```

Regards

Mike

Answer (score 0):

You could implement your own custom method to do the desired functionality.

First of all, if you would declare a set of custom structs, note that your struct *must* be [Hashable](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/hashable) protocol -which means that it implicitly must be [Equatable](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/equatable) -, thus it would be implemented as follows:

```
struct MyStruct: Hashable, Equatable {
    var x : Int
    var y : Int
    var z : Int

    // Hashable
    var hashValue: Int

    // Equatable
    static func ==(lhs: MyStruct, rhs: MyStruct) -> Bool {
        return lhs.x == rhs.x
    }
}
```

So, you could declare a set of `MyStruct`.

<sub>Probably this is not the right way to assign a value to the `hashValue`, but for the purpose of answering the question I will assign dummy values to them.</sub>

For implementing the method for achieving the desired output, I would recommend to declare it in a set *extension* (if you would let it also functional for arrays, you could declare it as a [Collection](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/collection) extension instead), constrained by the set element type:

```
extension Set where Element == MyStruct {
    func firstOrDefault(for expectedXValue: Int, defaultXValue: Int) -> MyStruct? {

        // expeccted
        if let expected = first(where: { $0.x == expectedXValue }) {
            return expected
        }

        // default
        if let defaultValue = first(where: { $0.x == defaultXValue }) {
            return defaultValue
        }

        // neither
        return nil
    }
}
```

Note that if there are more than one expected or default x value in the set, it would returns the first matched one.

You would notice that the main functionality of implementing `firstOrDefault` method is to use [`first(where:)`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/set/1848922-first) method (which is similar to what are you looking for), with a little bit of logic to get a -first- default value instead.

---

**Output:**

In case of there is an expected object with x = 7:

```
let mySet: Set<MyStruct> = [MyStruct(x: 1, y: 2, z: 3, hashValue: 101),
                            MyStruct(x: 4, y: 5, z: 6, hashValue: 102),
                            MyStruct(x: 7, y: 8, z: 100, hashValue: 103),
                            MyStruct(x: 9, y: 19, z: 12, hashValue: 104)]

let myObject = mySet.firstOrDefault(for: 7, defaultXValue: 4)
dump(myObject)

/*
 ▿ Optional(__lldb_expr_187.MyStruct(x: 7, y: 8, z: 9, hashValue: 102))
 ▿ some: __lldb_expr_187.MyStruct
 - x: 7
 - y: 8
 - z: 9
 - hashValue: 102
 */
```

In case of there is no expected value and the default x = 4:

```
let mySet2: Set<MyStruct> = [MyStruct(x: 1, y: 2, z: 3, hashValue: 101),
                            MyStruct(x: 4, y: 5, z: 6, hashValue: 102),
                            MyStruct(x: 1000, y: 8, z: 100, hashValue: 103),
                            MyStruct(x: 9, y: 19, z: 12, hashValue: 104)]

let myObject2 = mySet2.firstOrDefault(for: 7, defaultXValue: 4)
dump(myObject2)

/*
 ▿ Optional(__lldb_expr_249.MyStruct(x: 4, y: 5, z: 6, hashValue: 102))
 ▿ some: __lldb_expr_249.MyStruct
 - x: 4
 - y: 5
 - z: 6
 - hashValue: 102
 */
```

In case of there is no expected and no default value:

```
let mySet3: Set<MyStruct> = [MyStruct(x: 1, y: 2, z: 3, hashValue: 101),
                             MyStruct(x: 1000, y: 5, z: 6, hashValue: 102),
                             MyStruct(x: 1000, y: 8, z: 100, hashValue: 103),
                             MyStruct(x: 9, y: 19, z: 12, hashValue: 104)]

let myObject3 = mySet3.firstOrDefault(for: 7, defaultXValue: 4)
dump(myObject3) // - nil
```

Answer (score 0):

So the quick answer to your question is

```
let element = ss.first { $0.x == searchForX } ?? ss.first { $0.x == defaultX }
```

---

This can be turned a simple extension

```
extension Sequence {

    func first(_ criteria: (Element) -> Bool, orDefault: (Element) -> Bool) -> Element? {
        return first(where: criteria) ?? first(where: orDefault)
    }

}

let element = ss.first({ $0.x == searchForX }, orDefault: { $0.x == searchForX })
```

By making this an extension on `Sequence`, it will work for `Array`s and anything that implements `Sequence`.

---

If you are concerned about performance you can roll your own.

```
extension Sequence {

    func first(_ criteria: (Element) -> Bool, orDefault: (Element) -> Bool) -> Element? {
        var defaultElement: Element?
        for element in self {
            if criteria(element) { return element }
            if criteria(element) { defaultElement = element }
        }
        return defaultElement
    }

}
```